# Set the origin of element to center instead of top left (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this marker (which is a simple div) inside the triangle:
[image: triangle and marker]

The center of the marker should lie exactly in the centroid of the triangle.

As seen in the picture, it's not exactly in the centroid (it's a bit to the right, and possible to the bottom).

I'm using jquery ui `.draggable` method. Here is my css for the marker:

```
#marker {
  position: absolute;
  background: #808080;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: grab;
}
```

And here's my jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var triangle = $("#triangle");
  var marker = $("#marker");
  var coord = getTriangleCoordinates(triangle);
  var center = centroid(coord);

  $("#marker").hover(
    function () {
      // over
      $(this).css("filter", "brightness(0.8)");
    },
    function () {
      // out
      $(this).css("filter", "brightness(1)");
    }
  );

  $("#marker").mouseup(function () {
    $(this).css("background", "salmon");
  });

  $("#marker").draggable({
    drag: function (event, ui) {
      var offset = ui.offset;
      if (!bounded(offset, coord)) return false;
    }
  });

  marker.css("left", Math.round(center.left) - 5 + "px");
  marker.css("top", Math.round(center.top) - 5 + "px");

  console.log(coord);
});
```

How do I make the default position of the marker's **center** exactly in the centroid, while still being able to drag the marker?

I tried the `transform: translate(-50%, 0)`css property. Although it fixed the position, it messed up the dragging feature altogether.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: The CSS for that single element on its own, tells us rather little. We don't even know what the absolute positioning is in reference to, the viewport, or a positioned ancestor. Please show a proper [mre] of your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your marker element has width 50px and height 50px.

Assuming your centroid function returns the correct result, you are then positioning the top left corner of the marker (remember, it is basically a square) at a mere 5px offset from the actual centroid.

It needs to be offset by half its width and height so that its central point is at the centroid.

So change this:

```
  marker.css("left", Math.round(center.left) - 5 + "px");
  marker.css("top", Math.round(center.top) - 5 + "px");
```

To this:

```
  marker.css("left", Math.round(center.left) - 25 + "px");
  marker.css("top", Math.round(center.top) - 25 + "px");
```

For a more general solution, if for example the dimensions of the marker might change with viewport size or something, you can set the top left to the centroid and then `transform: translate(-50%, 50%)`. This will move the marker left and up by half its own width and height, whatever they are.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the positioning issue. Appreciate that!

Comment: I noticed that the marker doesn't go all the way to the left side of the triangle. And it overshoots on the right and bottom sides. When setting the `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` it fixes this behavior but when dragging the marker to any edge, the dragging stops working at all. Any idea what could be causing this? Here is the codepen if it helps: https://codepen.io/badijabbour/pen/ZEaWxMz